# Проблема с переходом на сцену в 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Реализовал переход на другую сцену с помощью коллайдера и этого скрипта:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class num1 : MonoBehaviour {
    private void OnMouseDown() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Lev3");
    }
}
```

но после компиляции и загрузки на телефон, на следующей сцене в этом же месте находится еще один коллайдер (при нажатии на который нас кидает на прошлую сцену).
Так вот из-за того что загрузка происходит моментально телефон успевает принять нажатие уже на новой сцене. Поэтому я пришел сюда за помощью в реализации задержки (одна секунда)в этом скрипте.

Comment: Синхронизация логики приложения по временной задержке - плохая идея. 1) чтобы "наверняка" сработало, вам нужно ждать намного дольше, чем необходимо, иначе есть риск, что не сработает. 2) если поменяется логика того, чего вы собираетесь ожидать, и время работы изменится, ваша задержка станет либо бесполезной, либо слишком долгой. Готовы ли вы сознательно добавлять тормоза в свое приложение? К тому же, оно не гарантирует корректную работу, то есть если телефон в ненужный момент затормозит (например входящий звонок), и секунды не хватит, юзер получит баг, от которого вы пытаетесь избавиться.

Comment: В приложении уже есть данного вида загрузки(после начала сцены через определенный промежуток времени загружается новая). проблема заключается в том что мне не хватает знаний в данном языке чтобы совместить эти скрипты и он работал.Помочь можете?)

Comment: То есть, я вам рассказываю, что вы делаете не так, а вы мне говорите "я уже так делал - всё работает". При чем тут знания языка? Это проблема проектирования логики.